# Javascript passing elementid in variable

Tags: javascript

I need to pass a variable to a javascript function which will then perform calculations and return the answer to another edit box on a form. I need to pass as I have 10 lines of edit boxes and dont want to have 10 seperate javascript functions.

```
function calc_totalcost(line)
{   
        $line_qty=line+"_qty";
    $line_totcost=line+"_totcost";
    $line_unitcost=line+"_unitcost";

    $totcost=$line_qty.value*$line_unitcost.value;
    document.getElementById('$line_totcost').value = $totcost;
}
```

on the html:

```
onchange="calc_totalcost('L1')"
```

So, on editbox 1 for L1_edit1 I need to send L1 to the function, which will then convert to 'L1_qty' which is an editbox (input) name where it will perform calculations using its contents. Hope that makes sense?
Thanks

Comment: Is there a question in there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few issues, including the last line in the function which does not need the document.getElementById whereas all the others do need it.

```
function calc_totalcost(line) {   
    var $line_qty     = document.getElementById(line+"_qty");
    var $line_totcost = document.getElementById(line+"_totcost");
    var $line_unitcost= document.getElementById(line+"_unitcost");

    var $totcost=$line_qty.value*$line_unitcost.value;
    $line_totcost.value = $totcost;
}
```